# Is there any way to make environmental objects more visible?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any way to do something to the environmental objects that can be interacted with (dead bodies, stumps, barrels etc) that is similar to how loot works.

Can I make the name (the same name that appears upon hover) be permanently next to the object as I can do so with loot?

Or is there any other way to somehow make it easier to spot these sometimes challenging to spot objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no, but you will surely not miss any important objects becasue they sparkle and are nearly impossible to miss. I think I have missed countless journal bags that have the lore information, but there is no way to highlight these things other than putting your cursor over them.